# Failed to Handle TAB Key Event In EXTJS Menu Items

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am facing an Issue while using TAB Key in EXT JS Menu Items. Issue is mainly related to TAB Key control indexing. I cannot navigate to different controls  with in Menus. It seems like Browser lost its Key Control.

I tried TABINDEX also, but no hope. Does anyone have any solution for this issue. I am using EXTJS 4.2.1

Thanks Advance....

Comment: Is it possible to find next UI element and set focus to that item.

Answer (score 1):

Tab key navigation will work only on anchor tags,input fields & buttons.In Extjs, all the buttons are made of anchor tag.
So, if your different controls with in Menus are not created using buttons,then tab key can't navigate to them